# How to transform a flattened data to a structured json?

Tags: python, json, graph, tree

**This is primary flattened element, aka input data:**

```
['a-ab-aba-abaa-abaaa', 'a-ab-aba-abab', 'a-ac-aca-acaa', 'a-ac-aca-acab']
```

**This is the target data what I need, aka output data:**

```
[
  {
    "title": "a",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "ab",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "aba",
            "children": [
              {
                "title": "abaa",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "title": "abaaa"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "title": "abab"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "ac",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "aca",
            "children": [
              {
                "title": "acaa"
              },
              {
                "title": "acab"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I thought I can use deep-for-loop iteration to generate this json data, but it's so difficult, because num of level will bigger than 10. so I think for-loop can't do in this process, is there any algrithm or use a packaged code to implement a function to achieve this target?
I'm so grateful if you share your mindset, god bless you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution using itertools. I dont know if this is efficient enough for your purpose, but it works. It works by transforming your list of strings into a list of lists, then dividing that into lists with the same first key, and then building the dict and repeating with the first key removed.

```
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

data = ['a-ab-aba-abaa-abaaa', 'a-ab-aba-abab', 'a-ac-aca-acaa', 'a-ac-aca-acab']
components = [x.split("-") for x in data]

def build_dict(component_list):
    key = lambda x: x[0]
    component_list = sorted(component_list, key=key)
    # divide into lists with the same fist key
    sublists = groupby(component_list, key)
    result = []

    for name, values in sublists:
        value = {}
        value["title"] = name
        value["children"] = build_dict([x[1:] for x in values if x[1:]])
        result.append(value)
    return result

pprint(build_dict(components))
```

Output:

```
[{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [],
                                                          'title': 'abaaa'}],
                                            'title': 'abaa'},
                                           {'children': [], 'title': 'abab'}],
                              'title': 'aba'}],
                'title': 'ab'},
               {'children': [{'children': [{'children': [], 'title': 'acaa'},
                                           {'children': [], 'title': 'acab'}],
                              'title': 'aca'}],
                'title': 'ac'}],
  'title': 'a'}]
```

To convert this dict to json you can use `json.dumps` from the json module. I hope my explanaition is clear.

Comment: This is a nice solution, I think maybe you could first check that `len(component_list) > 0` and then the body of the for loop would be a one-liner. But anyways +1))

Comment: Unbelievable, this way is efficient, million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
def populate_levels(dct, levels):
    if levels:
        if levels[0] not in dct:
            dct[levels[0]] = {}
        populate_levels(dct[levels[0]], levels[1:])


def create_final(dct):
    final = []
    for title in dct:
        final.append({"title": title, "children": create_final(dct[title])})
    return final


data = ['a-ab-aba-abaa-abaaa', 'a-ab-aba-abab', 'a-ac-aca-acaa', 'a-ac-aca-acab']
template = {}

for item in data:
    populate_levels(template, item.split('-'))

final = create_final(template)
```

I couldn't see a clean way of doing it all at once so I created this in-between `template` dictionary. Right now if a 'node' has no children its corresponding dict will contain `'children': []`
you can change this behavior in the `create_final` function if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def get_struct(d):
  _d = defaultdict(list)
  for a, *b in d:
     _d[a].append(b)
  return [{'title':a, 'children':get_struct(filter(None, b))} for a, b in _d.items()]

data = ['a-ab-aba-abaa-abaaa', 'a-ab-aba-abab', 'a-ac-aca-acaa', 'a-ac-aca-acab']
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(get_struct([i.split('-') for i in data]), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "title": "a",
    "children": [
        {
            "title": "ab",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "aba",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "abaa",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "title": "abaaa",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "abab",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "ac",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "aca",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "acaa",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "acab",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
             ]
          }
      ]
   }
]
```